# How to describe the unit ball as an Intersection of hyperplanes?

Tags: geometry, optimization, convex-optimization, convex-geometry

How can one describe the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ as an intersection of supporting halfspaces?

Answer (score 1):

Let $B_3\subset \mathbb{R}^3$ denote the unit ball. By *supporting halfspace*, I assume you mean an affine half space containing $B_3$ such that its boundary contains at least one boundary point of $B_3$. Taking
$$B_3=\bigcap_{|x|=1}\{x+z:\langle z,x\rangle\leq 0\}$$
should work. [Here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ihys2baair) is a good picture of the lower dimensional case; can you visualize what this looks like in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: Note that this answer also works in $\Bbb R^n$ for $n = 1, 2, 3, \ldots$. If it doesn't make sense initially, it's worth seeing how it works for $n = 1$.

Comment: It's quite hard to see the visualization. I'm trying to understand what you wrote. What abou if we want to do the same with a circle in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$? What would be the solution?

Comment: @Laura did you use the slider on the Desmos demonstration? It shows how this would work with a circle in $\mathbb{R}^2$. If you more detail beyond that, let me know and I will edit the answer.

Comment: What about if we have the closed ball in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$, how to write is as a intersection of supporting halfspaces?